# Create React App - Dev server conditional rewrite to index

Tags: reactjs, url-rewriting

I am using conditional rendering without React Router or any other routing module in `App.js`. I am also using `create-react-app` for the project, however it's been ejected using `npm run eject`. If I request `http://localhost:3000/privacy.html` it seems to rewrite me back to `http://localhost:3000/`. That is, I'm given the contents of the index file, while the URL remains unchanged. After the production build is put on the production server I am using Nginx to fix the issue on said machine, but how would I solve this on the development machine?

Also if there's an *easy* configuration setting to conditionally "rewrite" URLs back to index, please give it a mention. For instance, I still want `http://localhost:3000/35643`, or any URI which ends with numerics, to rewrite back to `http://localhost:3000/`, but not `http://localhost:3000/privacy.html`, which would be some sort of exception.

I'm a newbie to Webpack and all the features beside core React, so would highly appreciate generous explanation of the configuration.

Comment: You not use React Router, especially when you know about it? It is a good fit?

Comment: @vahdet No, I don't plan on integrating it into this project, but that shouldn't matter